# Tabcontrol Controlling other Controls

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I want to use TabControl1 in Form1; which contain 2 tabs; In tab 1; I inserted  RichTextBox1, Label1, and Button1; I want to use these 3 controls in both tabs; I tried the following code, but they are not showing in Tab 2; How to do this?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For sss = 1 To 100
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Label1.Text & " - No. - " & sss & vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MyTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim indexOfSelectedTab As Integer = TabControl1.SelectedIndex
    Dim selectedTab As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage = TabControl1.SelectedTab
    If indexOfSelectedTab = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Tab 0 Selected")
    ElseIf indexOfSelectedTab = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Tab 1 Selected")
        '************************************
        RichTextBox1.Show()
        Label1.Show()
        Button1.Show()
        '************************************
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out with the help of Gjaa code above;
I've got the final code as below; with this code you can control the contents of the richTextBox1 from Button1 or any tab of the tabControl:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    For s = 1 To 100
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Label1.Text & " - No. - " & s & vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    For s = 1 To 100
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(" Button2 - " & s & vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim indexOfSelectedTab As Integer = TabControl1.SelectedIndex
    Dim selectedTab As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage = TabControl1.SelectedTab
    With TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls
        .Add(RichTextBox1)
        .Add(Label1)
        .Add(Button1)
    End With
    If indexOfSelectedTab = 0 Then
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        For sss = 1 To 100
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(" Tab 0 - " & sss & vbCrLf)
        Next
    ElseIf indexOfSelectedTab = 1 Then
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        For sss = 1 To 100
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(" Tab 1 - " & sss & vbCrLf)
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
Private Sub MyTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    With MyTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls
       .Add(RichTextBox1)
       .Add(Label1)
       .Add(Button1)
    End With
    Select Case MyTabControl.SelectedIndex
       Case 0 'first tab
           RichTextBox1.Text = "I'm on the first tab"
           '...
       Case 1 'second tab
           RichTextBox1.Text = "Now on second tab"
    End Select
End Sub
```

This take the controls and move them to whatever tab you are.

Comment: Thanks Gjaa for the fast response; This code seems to keep the controls exactly in all tabs; I want to change the contents of |RichTextBox1 in Tab2 than Tab1; how to do this?

Comment: and label1.text in Tab1 similar to label1.text in Tab2?

Comment: If you want your controls to hold different content, you have to create two of each and put them in their own tab.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use If Statement to assign values based on which tab is clicked by user; I just wonder what is the way to do that; like ('MyTabControl.SelectedTab.Controls = 1')?

Comment: You can use the TabControl's `SelectedIndex` property. I added it to the code.